# how to pick pixel colour from picture GTK 3

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have image in pixbuf and viewed in GtkImage widget, Need Get pixel coordinates from cursor position and get that pixel value from the pixbuf.

user will move mouse over the image and pick any colour from that picture, i dont know what to use or best approach to pick colour from picture displayed in window

Comment: That is multiple tasks in one question. Getting pixel coordinates from cursor position and getting that pixel from the pixbuf. Which one is causing problems? Please show minimal reproducible example what you have tried so far.

Comment: i havn't tried any.. just showed pixbuf image in image viewer, I'm studying what is best approach for "Getting pixel coordinates from cursor position and getting that pixel from the pixbuf"..  i think making this pixbuf as drawable (cario).. then there may be some api to get pixel value from cursor position .. is it possible ? @Gerhardh

Comment: Then you have even 3 topics in one question. At SO any question should focus on one specific problem only. And it should contain a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your current effort.